# Angular 6 communicate between 2 components instances through service

Tags: angular, typescript, binding, angular-dynamic-components

I have a component that loads/remove another component dynamically by calling a service.
I also give the dynamically add component the ability to remove itself. My problem is notifying the other component that this instance of the dynamic component is removed.

I have tried to use event output/emit and subject/subscribe without luck. Not sure if I'm doing it wrong.

Here is my code, once the button clicked and the component gets added, if I use the close button inside the component the main button doesn't know about that and it will require 2 clicks to toggle right, plus the text of the button will be wrong

https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-row-components-for-smart-table

The problem I had when using the subject and subscribe it fires for all instances without efecting the button!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things to make it work , instead of subscribing a common subject or event emitter for all component , create a unique subject dynamically for each component. So it won't fire for all components. For that first you need to is provide a unique componentName for each component or you can use the id.

```
data = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'Leanne Graham',
      username: 'Bret',
      email: 'Sincere@april.biz',
      button: 'Button #1',
      componentName:"component"+1
    }
```

Step 2 : Register subjects for each row creation based the componentNae. On each close click the corresponding subscription will call and then you can remove the component from here

```
    ngOnInit() {
        this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase();
         this.InjiService.componentSubjects[this.rowData.componentName] = new Subject();
         this.InjiService.componentSubjects[this.rowData.componentName].subscribe(()=>{

          this.InjiService.removeComponent(this.expanededComp);
          this.expanededComp = null;
          //this.renderValue = this.value.toString().toUpperCase(); //"Open";
          this.isOpen = false;
          //firing the change detection manually
          this.ref.markForCheck();    
        });

  }
```

Please make sure you are declared the componentSubjects on your service

```
export class InjiService {
 public componentSubjects: { [name: string]: Subject<any> } = {};
```

[Working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamically-row-components-for-smart-table-kemmhg)